# Entity Framework 4 and Repository Pattern problem

Tags: entity-framework-4, repository-pattern

I am having trouble understanding if I am doing this correctly or not. I have 3 entities that are dependent on each other. I am trying to add new objects to these entities and then call save changes ultimately adding the corresponding records to the tables honoring the FK constraints.

I am getting the error:

**The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.**

[image]

In my code I am parsing some XML with linq while adding the new objects to the context as I go. In my service layer I have the following method to handle processing the incoming data.

```
public void ProcessSurvey(int surveyContentId, int caseNo, string surveyTitle, string reportVersion, string reportXml)
{
    // get surveyid 
    var surveyContent = _surveyContentRepository.GetSurveyContent(surveyContentId);
    // create response obj
    var surveyResponse = new SurveyResponse()
    {
        SurveyId = surveyContent.SurveyId,
        CaseNo = caseNo,
        SurveyTitle = surveyTitle,
        ReportVersion = reportVersion,
        Created = DateTime.Now,
        ResponseXML = reportXml
    };
    // add response obj to context?
    _surveyResponseRepository.Add(surveyResponse);
    // get the questions elements from the xml data
    var questions = SurveyResponseHelper.GetResponseQuestions(reportXml);
    // iterate over questions
    foreach (XElement question in questions)
        {
        SurveyQuestion thisSurveyQuestion = SurveyResponseHelper.ProcSurveyQuestion(question, surveyContentId);
        // add question?
        _surveyQuestionRepository.Add(thisSurveyQuestion);
        // get question answer
        SurveyAnswer thisSurveyAnswer = SurveyResponseHelper.GetAnswer(question);
        //update the answer with the question and response obj to satisfy the FK reference
        thisSurveyAnswer.SurveyQuestion = thisSurveyQuestion;
        thisSurveyAnswer.SurveyResponse = surveyResponse; // This is where it breaks ERRROR: The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects
        _surveyAnswerRepository.Add(thisSurveyAnswer);
        }
    //commit
    _surveyAnswerRepository.Save();
}
```

My Repositories look like this..

```
public interface ISurveyAnswerRepository
{
    void Add(SurveyAnswer surveyAnswer);
    void Save();
}
public class SurveyAnswerRepository : Repository, ISurveyAnswerRepository
{

    //private DiversionProgramsEntities _db;

    public SurveyAnswerRepository()
    {
        //_db = new DiversionProgramsEntities();
    }

    public void Add(SurveyAnswer surveyAnswer)
    {
        this.DataContext.SurveyAnswers.AddObject(surveyAnswer);


    }

    public void Save()
    {
        this.DataContext.SaveChanges();

    }
```

my base repository

```
public class Repository
{
    private DiversionProgramsEntities _dataContext;

    public DiversionProgramsEntities DataContext
    {
        get { return _dataContext ?? (_dataContext = DatabaseFactory.CreateContext()); }
    }


}
```

and static class / method to create the context

```
public static class DatabaseFactory
{

    public static DiversionProgramsEntities CreateContext()
    {
        return new DiversionProgramsEntities();
    }

}
```

here is my helper code..

```
public class SurveyResponseHelper
{
public static IEnumerable<XElement> GetResponseQuestions(string xmlResponseData)
{
    XElement xmlData = XElement.Parse(xmlResponseData);
    var questions = from n in xmlData.Descendants()
                    where n.Parent.Name.LocalName == "questions"
                    select n;

    return questions;
}

public static SurveyQuestion ProcSurveyQuestion(XElement question, int surveyContentId)
{
    // get the question type
    var questionType = question.Name.LocalName;
    // get question element text. This is the actual question text
    var questionText = question.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "direction").SingleOrDefault().Value;
    // check to see if this question exists in the data table, if it does then we will use the questionid from that which will get used to tie the SurveyAnswer to this question.
    // if question does not already exist then a new one will be created
    SurveyQuestionRepository surveyQuestionRepository = new SurveyQuestionRepository();
    SurveyQuestion surveyQuestion;
    surveyQuestion = surveyQuestionRepository.GetSurveyQuestion(surveyContentId, questionType, questionText);
    if (surveyQuestion == null)
    {
        surveyQuestion = new SurveyQuestion()
        {
            QuestionText = questionText,
            QuestionType = questionType,
            SurveyContentId = surveyContentId
        };
    }

    return surveyQuestion;
}

public static SurveyAnswer GetAnswer(XElement question)
{
    // get the answer index value
    var answers = question.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "answers").SingleOrDefault();
    int userAnswerIndex = Int32.Parse(answers.Attribute("userAnswerIndex").Value);
    // move the answers to an array so we can use the index to get the correct answer
    XElement[] answersArray = answers.Elements().ToArray();
    SurveyAnswer answer = new SurveyAnswer()
    {
        AnswerText = answersArray[userAnswerIndex].Value
    };

    return answer;
}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @TimHoolihan stated the issue is that you are not using the same Data Context for accessing the Survey Responses and Survey Questions and actually I believe the issue lines in the line below from the ProcSurveyQuestion method.

```
    SurveyQuestionRepository surveyQuestionRepository = new SurveyQuestionRepository();
```

I see that you have a singleton DataContext in the DiversionProgramsEntities class, but I cannot infer from your code if the SurveyQuestionRepository and SurveryResponseRepositories are also using that same context. Based on the error you are getting, I am guessing that they are using separate contexts, so again as @TimHoolihan suggested, you need to modify your code to use the same context for both.

You should also look into the [UnitOfWork](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) pattern as this is what you are trying to accomplish here, but you do not have a common context to track all of your changes across.

Comment: I thought I had a common context, all my repositories use the same base repository which is where the context is created from a static factory method. If I new up an instance of one of my entities outside of one of my repositories are you saying that puts that instance in it's own context?

Comment: I reworked things and implemented UnitOfWork and a generic Repository pattern. This fixed my current problem but now I have discovered a new issue with violating primary key constraint with EF attempting to insert duplicate keys.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the error is describing perfectly what is going on. In the following line:

```
var questions = SurveyResponseHelper.GetResponseQuestions(reportXml);
```

You are getting a question from another class. That class probably creates it's own object context.

You can't attach a question to the answer if they are from different object contexts.

To solve this, the easiest way is to add a parameter to your methods GetResponseQuestions for the datacontext, so your other method can use that the repositories datacontext to get the questions.

Also, various IoC methods would simplify this.

Comment: The SurveyResponseHelper.GetResponseQuestions() method just returns an IEnumerable<XElement>. While iterating over those I use the SurveyResponseHelper.ProcSurveyQuestion() method to return a SurveyQuestion object and I am not using the context just using new SurveyQuestion in there..

Answer (score 1):

Where does your `_surveyContentRepository` come from? If it's static I could see a scenario where that holds on to a `SurveyContent` object which is attached to one `DiversionProgramsEntities`, and your `ProcSurveyQuestion()` method finds and returns an existing `SurveyQuestion`, attached to a different `DiversionProgramsEntities`.

Other than that, I think a general pointer I can give you is to assign objects to each other using the objects themselves rather than the object Ids, so instead of:

```
var surveyResponse = new SurveyResponse { SurveyId = surveyContent.SurveyId }
```

...use:

```
var surveyResponse = new SurveyResponse { Survey = surveyContent }
```

This automatically adds your new `SurveyResponse` object to the same object context to which the `SurveyContent` object belongs, and means you don't have to manually add anything to a repository. You can assemble your entire object graph like this, then call `Save()` on the repository you used to retrieve the first object to save the whole thing.

Comment: Steve, my repository instances are new'ed up in the service class constructor. This was an existing app so I did not want to try and factor in an Ioc container. I have a private field for each repo instance that is initialized in the constructor method.